# 回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか

Tags: 討議

「[ニューロンを模した大量のプロセッサによる非同期処理は、なぜ高速なのか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2829)」 において、
回答後に質問が大幅に修正される事例が発生しました。

その上で [以下のような要求](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2829/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C-%E9%9D%9E%E5%90%8C%E6%9C%9F%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%AF%E9%AB%98%E9%80%9F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B/2838?noredirect=1#comment1709_2838) がコメントとして寄せられています。

> 質問文を変更しました。編集が必要になった箇所もあるかと思いますので、よろしくお願いします。

私はこれを、あまり好ましくない状況だと感じています。

いくつか対応方法はあると思うのですが SO 的にはどうするのが正しいと考えるのでしょうか?

- そもそもこのような大幅の質問の変更はするべきではない

  - 新たに質問しなおして元のは放置するかクローズする、とか
- 回答を訂正すべきである

  - 回答者が訂正すべき
  - 回答者以外が訂正して良い
- 新たな回答を付けるべきである

Comment: Meta [Answered a question; question changed via follow-up answer - unsure of relevance anymore](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275071) ・ [How to deal with questions that change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177173/), 少し状況が違いますが [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/) あたりを見ると，本家SO では「そもそもそうした変更をするべきでない」というのが主流のようですね．

Comment: 本件よりは穏やかな例ですが、Meta投稿「[回答の中に質問者から回答者への返信を書くのはわかりにくい?](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/330/)」も類似ケースかと思います。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

さすがにこれだけ変更する場合は、新しく質問したほうがよいのではないかと思います。

質問を使いまわす場合の問題は、

- 回答者が戻ってきて回答を訂正する保証がない、他の人が編集できる内容とも限らない
- 古い回答と新しい回答が混ざって見づらくなる可能性がある
- 投票結果の意味が失われる

Comment: 質問を大幅に変更することで、回答するだけの価値があった質問が失われる、という問題もあると思いました。

Answer (score 6):

「質問は、質問者がサイトに書き込んだ時点から共有物になる」と考えますので、私は
質問者またはモデレータが元に戻す、もしくは新しく質問し直すのが良いと思います。

今回は、私がクローズ票を受け取ったときに、「コメントされることを通じて、質問者
自らが動きわかりやすい質問に変えること」が、サイトの仕組みを最大活用した非常に
好ましいケースだと判断しましたので、クローズ票を無視するかわりに質問にコメント
を残すことにしました。１２月下旬と１月上旬で別々にクローズ票が届いたということ
は、この質問が生き残るためには、今後も試練を何度も乗り越えなければならなくなる
ことを意味しています。私自身回答を半分用意していたので質問には消えてほしくない
とも考えコメントしました。大げさなことになってしまい申し訳ないです。

一方で、回答がついた質問には、「回答者か質問について考えを巡らし、文章にした時
間と労力」が付加されているとも考えています。質問者であるないに関わらず、内容を
劇的に変えることは、回答者の労力と主張を奪うオフェンシブな行為だと考えます。

幸い、このサイトでは質問は誰でも変更でき、モデレータもついていますので、質問を
元に戻すことは可能です。そうしたほうが良いと考えます。（一般ユーザーである私が
やると上書きし合う不毛なやりとりになる可能性があり、私は手をつけられない。）

ただし、時間が経ってなお、質問者さんが気分を害する記録が残っているのは良くない
と考えますので、個人的には、質問を元に戻し、指摘コメントなどを、削除しておくべ
きかと思っています。

質問者はサイトの使い方を理解するまで、すこし時間がかかっているだけでしょうから
今後も継続して様々なことを質問し、学んでほしいです。

Comment: 今回の質問ではモデレーターの私がロールバックしましたが、それは「モデレーターとして鶴の一声をあげた」というよりは、このメタ投稿での意見の大勢をみて代理実行した、という方が(心情としては)近いです。メタでの議論と結論があれば、モデレーター以外のユーザーでも上書き戦争にはなりにくいかなと思います。

Comment: コメントを頂いたことで実態を受け入れどのように編集したら良いのか考えることが出来ました。結果的にうまく編集できず、質問自体を変更する方法しか思い浮かびませんでした。がentoさんが編集してくださりどうにか形になりました。ありがとうございます

Comment: 迅速に対応してくださり、ありがとうございました。質問者にとっても質問に対するコントロールを失わない結果になり、良いようになったと思います。私の反省としては、ユーザー間で解決努力がもう少し必要だったと考えています。質問が多くなりだしたら、個々の対応は大変になるでしょうから。。。