# 質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？

Tags: 討議

既出だったら申し訳ありません。

例えば [swiftのAVAudioPlayerのループ再生](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6533) のように内容としては難しくはないが質問の仕方が良いとは言えない質問があった場合、サイト全体の質を上げるために皆あえて回答していないのだろうか（なので回答を控えるべきか）と迷うことが少なからずあります。

ぱっと思いつく対応方法は下記のような感じなのですが、  
こういった場合はどうすべきでしょうか？  
・そのまま放置する
・反対票を入れる
・コメントで改善を促す
・回答を記載して、次回からもう少し質問の仕方を工夫した方が良いという内容を添える

すでに反対票が入っているのでそれが良いのかもしれませんが、
個人的に反対票を入れるだけというのもどうなのかなと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 質問の仕方が良いとは言えない質問があった場合、サイト全体の質を上げるために皆あえて回答していないのだろうか（なので回答を控えるべきか）と迷うことが少なからずあります。

回答に際しても、個々人の考え方やスタイルがあると思いますので、以下一つの参考までに。

> ・そのまま放置する
>   ・反対票を入れる
>   ・コメントで改善を促す
>   ・回答を記載して、次回からもう少し質問の仕方を工夫した方が良いという内容を添える

スタックオーバーフロー的には、「コメントで改善を促す」か「そのまま放置」が良いと考えています（少なくとも私は）。

「反対票を入れる」は、本当にそこまで酷いか？は再考したうえで、それでもダメだと思ったら反対投票すればよいかと。

「回答を記載して、次回からの改善アドバイス」は、賛否が分かれる点かと思います。個人的には **技術質問に対する回答** と **人の行動に対する助言** を混ぜるのは、避けるべきと考えてます。FAQサイトとしては後者は単なるノイズですし、他サイトでたまに見られる「説教くさい」雰囲気をかもしがちです。（極端なケースでは、技術回答よりも人生訓的なノリになってしまいます）

技術的な回答のみを付ければよいと思います。どうしても言いたいことがあるなら、コメントにでも書けばよいでしょうし、それも嫌なら最初から放置すればよいという考え方です。

---

余談：背景にある考え方として、私はFAQサイトの質は“個々の質問の質が高いこと”と捉えていません。どちらかと言えば、まずは質より量であり、量が質に転化するという考え方です。無理に1質問の品質を持ち上げるより、別のよりよい質問と回答がたくさんなされれば、結果的にはFAQサイトの質があがるだろうというスタンスです。

Answer (score 3):

回答として得られるものも、しっかりとしたした説明や解説ではなく、[短い回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)がつきやすいために[マイナス票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)が付いていると思います。

自分自信がそのクラスについてどの程度の理解をしているのか、それはプロパティに設定できる値の何％なのか、共有する必要はありませんか？
参考：[どんな時に質問したらいいですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)

この質問が問題なのは、ループ再生以外の方法以外でも複数の質問が混在できるところにあります。
[例えばループ再生、再生、回数を指定した分だけ繰り返しサウンドファイルを再生する](http://ios.ch3cooh.jp/entry/20120521/1337526000)
それぞれの機能について独立した質問が可能ですが、プロパティに設定できる値についての質問だとしたら質問回答ともに役に立つかと思います。
参考：[質問は細かく細分化するべき？それとも、得た回答から話を飛躍させても良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1663/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AF%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F%E7%B4%B0%E5%88%86%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82-%E5%BE%97%E3%81%9F%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%A9%B1%E3%82%92%E9%A3%9B%E8%BA%8D%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84)

コメントすることも必要でしょうが、コメントをたくさん頂いても回答が得られるわけではありません。
コメントを頂くたびに質問者は期待します。しかし、実際はコメントの数が多いと必ず回答が多いかというとそうでもないです。お店でいうところの冷やかしに感じられてしまいます。回答が確実に行える方がコメントを残すのが良いかと思います。

また、質問を削除するにも２つ以上回答がついてしまうと、質問者は質問が削除できなくなり、一つの場合で投票が行われていた場合も削除できません。こうなってしまうと、質問を良い物に変更しようとしても改善の見込みはありません。
参考：[回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E5%B9%85%E3%81%AA%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B)

全体としての参考
[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595/%E8%A9%B2%E5%BD%93%E5%88%86%E9%87%8E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E%E7%9A%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%8D%E5%BF%9C)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。コメントや回答に関する記述等参考になりました。同じ質問（の記述）でも見る人によって感じ方は異なると思いますので、少し様子を見てみようと思います。

Comment: @ita_3y [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 　 [どこでもコメント](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)　*同じ質問（の記述）でも見る人によって感じ方は異なると思いますので*　もし、質問を履き違えているのだとしたらそのことを伝えるコメントを残すべきでは？

Comment: _同じ質問（の記述）でも見る人に‌​よって感じ方は異なると思いますので_ これはこの質問および回答に対してではなく「質問の仕方が良いとは言えない質問」に対してのコメントです。

Answer (score 1):

stackoverflow はコミュニティからの信用度によって可能な操作権限があると思いますので、
・質問の編集権限を持っている場合
　よりわかりやすい質問内容に編集
・質問の編集権限を持っていない場合
　放置
でいいのかなと思っております。
僕は英語版 stackoverflow で稚拙な英語で質問したときに、他のユーザーの方に質問内容を編集していただき、非常に感謝をしました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。英語の場合は言いたいことをうまく伝えるのが難しいのでネイティブの方や英語が堪能な方のお力添えをいただけるとありがたいのは同意です。ただ（おそらく多くの質問者にとって）日本語は母国語ですし、質問する側も自分の質問に責任を持って投稿した方が良いのかなと思ったりします（ただ質問するだけでなく、伝わりやすいようにできるだけ推敲する。自分なりに調べたことがあると理想的）。あまり堅苦しく考えると変に敷居が上がってしまって良くないと思いますが、「〜が分かりません。教えて下さい。」みたいな質問が乱立するのも避けたいなぁと考えています。