# 「コードが思い浮かびません」という質問はどう聞けばよいですか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

[「特定の文字列が出力されるまで処理を繰り返し、出力されたら処理を停止したい」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6407/1)

について、「スタックオーバーフローは僕の代わりにこういうプログラムを作って下さい、というサイトではないはず」というコメント<sup>1</sup>があり、プラス票が1つ付いていました。一方質問にもプラス票は付いていて、評価が分裂しているようです。

確かに[最初の版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6407/1)は「こういうことがしたいです」という要件のみで、人によっては「くれくれ質問」と見なすかもしれません。ただし実現したいこと自体ははっきりしており、回答も付いています。

[現在の第5版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6407/5)は「こういうことがしたいのですが方法が分かりません、教えてください」という形式になり、「方法が分からない」という情報と書きたいコードの骨組みが追加されています。

1. 初版の状態で質問としては問題ないと考えますか？
2. 問題あり、と考える場合、どう改善すればよいでしょうか。また、現在の版ではどうでしょうか。
3. 「スタックオーバーフローは僕の代わりにこういうプログラムを作って下さい、という場ではない」と考えますか？その場合、問題ない質問との境界はどのあたりにあるのでしょう。

みなさんのご意見をお聞かせください。

**英語版メタやメタSEの関連する議論:**

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/157841
- [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/157841)
- [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035/157841)
- [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/157841)
- [What close reason should I use for give me teh codez?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253137/20226)
- [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/20226)

<sup>あとで要約を書く...かも。</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>当該コメントはモデレーション上の理由から削除済みです。</sup>

Comment: ここスタックオーバーフローに限らず、本質的には同じ問題だと思いますので、「[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html)」も参考に挙げておきます。

Comment: おお、分かりやすくてよい資料ですね。[ヘルプセンターの「良い質問をするには?」](/help/how-to-ask)にある ["How to ask questions the smart way"](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) へのリンク（日本語版ではリンクになってないですが）はそちらにした方がよさそうです。

Answer (score 5):

初版の段階でも意図はおおむね伝わったので質問としては成立していると考えます。マイナス票理由にある「解決しようと努力した」と言えるかというと正直言えないレベルですが、この質問は「pingの結果を出力文字列で判断する」というありがちなミスを犯しており、ナレッジとしてもそれなりに価値がある質問ではある、というのが回答しようと判断した大きな理由です。

一般論として、「これこれこういうことを実現したいがどのように書いたらよいのか」というのはプログラミングにおいて極めてありふれた質問なので、それが不可ということはあり得ないでしょう。

この質問については、質問の内容が内容なので回答は結果としてスクリプト作成代行にしかならないわけですが、「結果として」そうなるものの責任を事前に質問者に問うのは因果が逆転しています。

質問の内容が初歩的過ぎる、調べればすぐ分かることである、ということで批判するのであればマイナス票によって行えばよいでしょう。質問として認められるか否かという話になると基準が必要ですがそれを定めて運用するのは言うまでも無く不可能です。

Answer (score 1):

[典型的な課題丸投げ質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2912/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%82%92%E5%88%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)をした(正確には,仕様が曖昧なまま質問した)立場から申しますと文面は第五版が丁寧かと思います。
（タイトルについては初版のほうがわかりやすく感じます。

文面に問題がないと判断した点は、

> 特定の出力がされるまで処理を繰り返し、出力されたら処理を停止する方法がわからないので、ご教示ください。

この具体的な不明な箇所の情報は有益で同じ 問題/疑問 を抱えた人に利益をもたらし同時に多くの人に好奇心を持たせます。

参考

> どんな時に質問したらいいですか?
> よい質問はいつでも歓迎します。ただし、まず課題をこなして調査結果を共有できる場合です。
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts

---

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)の利用法ですが、お礼などを極力避け、建設的な批判を残すことが推奨されていますが、私見的な批判文を残すことは推奨されていません。
この場合の建設的な批判とは解決に必要な疑問文のことを指すと私は考えています。
解決の糸口を持っている人がコメントを残すのが適切かと思います。
もし、それがレビューの権限を与えられた人物による初めての投稿する人へのサイト利用法の指導だとしたら問題は感じませんが、そのような権限を与えれていない人物によるサイト利用法の指導だとしたら問題があると思います。

参考

> 「ありがとう」というために自分の質問や回答にコメントをつけないでください。コメントは、明確化のリクエスト、建設的な批判を残す、関係するがささいな追加情報の追加のためにあるもので、交流のためのものではありません。
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
>
> 初めての投稿キューには、上手な質問や回答の仕方や、このサイトでトピックに沿っているもの、外れているものは何かをよく理解していない可能性のある新規ユーザーが質問した最初の数件の投稿が含まれます。
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

質問の仕方に関する参考
[質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1678/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E6%96%B9%E3%81%8C%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)
[該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595/%E8%A9%B2%E5%BD%93%E5%88%86%E9%87%8E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E%E7%9A%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%8D%E5%BF%9C)