# デバッグ方法を勉強すべき質問について

Tags: 討議

直接の回答よりも、デバッグ方法についてもっと勉強した方が良いのでは、
と思える質問を度々見かけます。
最近ですと、以下の質問です。

[strtokの返り値をstrcpyするとSegfaultするのはなぜですか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9663/)

segmentation fault が起きてるなら、引数がどうなっているのか位
調べられるでしょうに...

こういった質問に対し、「デバッグ方法を勉強してくれ」の旨を伝えるためには、
どうするのが良いのでしょうか。

回答として書くのはおかしいと思うので、質問に対するコメントで書くべきなの
でしょうか。しかしコメントでも質問内容からすると脇道に逸れすぎかな、と
思えます。

それとも、そんなことは大きなお世話で、質問に対する直接の回答だけあれば
良いのでしょうか?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 回答として書くのはおかしいと思うので、質問に対するコメントで書くべきなの
>   でしょうか。しかしコメントでも質問内容からすると脇道に逸れすぎかな、と
>   思えます。

確かに「デバッグ方法を勉強してくれ」とだけ言うのは、Q&Aとして役立つ情報かと言われると微妙なところです。技術的というより、回答の仕方についての指摘にも見えます。

参考 [質問の仕方が良いとは言い難い質問への回答はどうしたら良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1687/8000)

そのかわりに、具体的なヒントを回答に書き添えるのはいかがでしょうか。

> **答えにたどり着いた理由として**
>   「～のようにして調べたところ××ということがわかりました。これを解決するには～」
>
> **アドバイス**
>   「このようなエラーは～のようにすると調査しやすいです」
>   「○○や××はよく嵌るポイントですから、～などで勉強されることをお勧めします」

具体的な情報は、その問題にはまっていない人にも役立つことがありますし、あるいはよりよい方法をコメントしてもらえるかもしれません。そうなればしめたものだと思います。