# 投稿者と他のユーザーの間で編集合戦になるのを防ぐために

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 編集

[deque関数を受け取ったキューの先頭を返し、 先頭以外が残るようにしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/11694)

この質問には元々ソースコードとそれに関する質問が書かれていましたが、回答された後になって、**質問者が**コードを削除しました。その後、**他のユーザーによって**コードは復元されましたが、投稿者による削除と、さらに別のユーザーによる復元が何度か繰り返されました。

編集合戦はWikiサイトなどでも見かける問題です。しかし多くのWikiでは編集者が対等で、個人の意見を押し通すべきでないとされているのに対し、ここはQ&Aサイトです。役に立つQ&Aを目指して編集するのはいいことだと思いますが、質問者の意思を尊重すべきとも思います。

では、編集合戦になりそう、あるいはなってしまった質問に、どのように対応するとよいでしょうか。

- 投稿者の編集に任せる
- （投稿者によって差し戻されようが）ロールバックを繰り返す
- モデレーター権限で編集をロックする
- コメント等で編集の理由を尋ねる
- etc.

また、仮に投稿者の編集を受け入れるとするならば、既存の回答が編集後の質問に合わない場合があります。これは削除等するべきでしょうか？

参考

- [回答後の質問の大幅な変更にはどのようにアクションすべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1558/8000)
- [Wikipedia:編集合戦 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88%E6%88%A6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

当ネットワークでは編集合戦対策として、基本的には３ステップで対応しています：

1. コメントで問題提起して、理由を伝えます
2. 削除されたコンテンツを復活させます
3. 上記をおこなっても編集合戦になってしまったら、モデレーターからメッセージを送ります

#### コメントで問題提起して、理由を伝えます

当サイトではsayuriが言ったように「質問は、質問者がサイトに書き込んだ時点から共有物になる」ことが正しいです。Q&Aによる情報の蓄積を目指しているため、質問者への回答以上に、同じ問題を抱えている人のことを考えてサイトを作りました。他のサイトとコンセプトが異なるため、第一歩は説明することです：

> スタック・オーバーフローでは質問者の役に立つだけでなく、将来このQ&Aを見にくるユーザーの役にも立ちたいと考えています。そのためにも、回答を得てから自分のコンテンツを削除しないでください。もし何かの理由で削除する必要があったら（個人情報が含まれている、共有する権限の無いコードなど）、[通報](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)または[問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)をしてください。ひとまず、削除された内容を復活させます。

#### 削除されたコンテンツを復活させます

コメントをした上でコンテンツを復活させてください。これで将来のユーザーが使える形に戻ります。

もし削除の理由がわかったら（例えば、個人情報やAPIキーが含まれている）、上記のようなコメントは書き込まず、モデレーターに知らせてください（通報で）。もしセンシティブな情報が入っていたら、モデレーター側でその情報を削除した上で投稿を復活させることができます。

#### 編集合戦になってしまったら、モデレーターからメッセージ

上記のステップを踏まえた上でも編集合戦になってしまったら、モデレーターに通報してください。

モデレーターはユーザーにプライベートメッセージを送る（又はアカウント停止する）ことができます。まだメッセージは日本語訳されていませんが、下記のようなメッセージになります：

- 最近自分のコンテンツを削除しています。当サイトは情報共有サイトのため、当コミュニティから回答を得てからその質問自体は当コミュニティの資産の一部になります。質問者に投稿が不要になっても、基本的には共有された投稿は残します。
- 自分のコンテンツを削除し続けられないように、とりあえずアカウントを停止しました。停止状態では信用度が１になり、サイトに参加できなくなります。停止が取り消されると、元の信用度等にもどります。
- 当サイトの運用モデルがわからないか、他の勘違いがある可能性も高いため、当メッセージに返事してください。何かの理由で削除しないといけなかったら、ご教示ください。私に返事したくない場合、[問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)を使っても構いません。

目的は：

1. 事情を説明し
2. 編集合戦・投稿の連続削除を停止し
3. ユーザー側の声を聞かせる場を作ること

このケースが起こる理由は悪用目的ではない可能性が高いので、コミュニケーションで解決するケースは多いと思います。ステップ 1. と 2. だけで出来るだけ対応しましょう。もし必要ならモデレーターに通報してください。

Answer (score 8):

> コメント等で編集の理由を尋ねる

個人的にはまずはここからスタートするのが良いかなと思います。
もしかしたら「投稿した後で質問、あるいはコード内に秘匿すべき情報を含めてしまっていたことに気が付いて慌てて削除した」といった事情がある可能性もあるので。

理由を尋ねても返信が無く、編集のみを繰り返すようであれば

> モデレーター権限で編集をロックする

で良いと思います（その旨は周知する必要があるとは思いますが）。

投稿者、閲覧者、どちらの編集を活かすかは判断が難しいところですが、
今回、題材として取り上げた質問のように「投稿者の削除に対して、複数の閲覧者がロールバックを行っている」という状態であれば「削除しない方が良いと考えているユーザが多数」であると考えられるため、ロールバックした方がQ&Aサイトとして有益だと判断して良いかなと思います。

以下、気になる点（回答で逆に質問を書いていて申し訳ないのですが・・・）

- 全ての質問をモデレーターが監視するのは大変
  →「通報」を活用すればモデレーターに連絡できる？
- ロックされた質問を（正当な理由で）どうしても編集したい場合は？

Comment: そうですね、モデレーターに連絡したい時、ロックされているが編集すべきだという場合は「通報」を使えばいいと思います。（「どういう理由で」「何を求めるのか」が通報コメントに書かれていると対応しやすいと思います）

Answer (score 4):

stackoverflowはQ&AサイトではなくQ&Aを蓄積するサイトではないでしょうか。参考の中で[Hiroshi Yamamotoさん](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1560/4236)が書かれている

> 「質問は、質問者がサイトに書き込んだ時点から共有物になる」

が今回にも当てはまると思います。質問をし回答を得られたら質問を消すという行為は、回答者に対する侮辱であり適切な利用方法とはいえないと思います。

Comment: 質問者に求める利用方法はそのようなものとして、それを守ってらえない場合はどのように対応するとよいだろう、編集合戦をするしかないのだろうか、というのが今回の疑問です。