# 未翻訳ヘルプ: "ロックされた投稿"について

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts
このヘルプが全体的に翻訳されていないので翻訳をお願いします。

関連項目
[投稿者と他のユーザーの間で編集合戦になるのを防ぐために](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1857/%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E8%80%85%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E9%96%93%E3%81%A7%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88%E6%88%A6%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92%E9%98%B2%E3%81%90%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AB/1859#1859) - "Edit wars"の翻訳『編集合戦』について。英語版ではブログにつながっている
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community - Communityユーザー(システム)も投稿のロックが可能です

Comment: 翻訳ボランティアの方へ：ヘルプページに関しては、どなたかが翻訳案をメタに投稿して下さりそれに対して vote が集まれば、モデレーターがヘルプページに反映します。このメタ質問への回答として案をご投稿頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 3):

[What is a locked post?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) を元に翻訳してみました。改善案がありましたら直接編集、またはコメントで指摘をお願いします。

---

### ロックされた投稿とは何ですか？

「ロック」された投稿は、如何なる変更も出来なくなります。具体的には以下のことができません。

- 投稿への投票 (質問のクローズ/再オープン投票を含む)
- 投稿の編集
- 投稿へのコメント
- 質問に対する回答
- 通報 (ただし重要な履歴情報の維持を目的としたロックの場合を除き、「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として通報することは可能です。下の方の説明もご覧ください)

### 誰が投稿をロックできますか？

[サイトのモデレーター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) は、質問と回答に対して下で示すようなロックを施すことが出来ます。

また、特定の状況においては[システムが自動で](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1418)投稿をロックします:

- 投稿が「スパム」や「暴言」として通報され、削除された場合。
- 投稿が別のサイトに移行された場合。
- 投稿が現在のサイトに移行されて拒否された場合。
- 質問が別の質問にマージされた場合、回答は移動され、元の質問はロックされます。

### 投稿のロックはどれくらいの期間、実施されますか？

誰がどのようにロックしたかによって期間が異なります。

- モデレーターが投稿をロックした場合、ロックを維持する期間を選択する必要があります (選択肢：1時間、1日、1週間、無期限)。指定した期間を過ぎると、システムが自動的にロックを解除します。
- システムが投稿をロックした場合、ロックは無期限に設定されます。モデレーターだけがロックを解除できます。

モデレーターはいつでも必要に応じて、ロックされた投稿のロックを手動で解除することができます。

### どんな場合に投稿をロックする必要がありますか？

原則として、投稿への変更がサイト上で重大な問題を引き起こしている場合は、**一時的なロック**をするべきです。例えば以下のケースです。

- [編集合戦](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)
- 口論などによるコメントの肥大化 ([コメントをモデレートするためのガイド](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)も参照してください)
- メタに関する議論の中で論争の的になるような投稿

**無期限のロック**は、システム自体によって課せられたものを除いて基本的には使用すべきではありません。ただし例外が2つあります:

1. 非常に人気だった質問が後にサイトにそぐわないものであったと考えられるようになった場合、その投稿は「重要な履歴情報の維持」を目的としてロックされます。このロックによってその質問は見た目が変わり、すべての回答も自動的にロックされ、更にどんな通報もできなくなります。このタイプのロックは、歴史的に大切だがこうでもしないと削除されてしまうようなものを守るために使ってください。それ以外の用途で**使わないでください**。
2. 「コミュニティwiki」による回答は[信用度の低いユーザーでも編集が可能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)です。投稿は複数の作成者に帰属し、元の作成者の評価には影響を与えません。複数の作成者によって情報を編集する必要がある場合に便利です (例えば、サイト自体のリソースやドキュメントのリストを編集する場合)。このような場合、質問をロックすることによって質問がクローズされるのを防いだり、他の回答が追加されてしまうのを防いだりすることができます。

#### 参考

- [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) -- Meta Stack Exchange
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) -- Meta Stack Exchange
- [高度な検索オプション](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: 反映いたしましたが、タイトルの変更完了までは少し時間がかかりますのでしばしお待ちください m_ _m